# Create hierarchy from csv in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv with the following data:

```
world,country,state

World,US,CA

World,US,NJ

World,INDIA,OR

World,INDIA,AP

World,INDIA,TN
```

I need to convert in to a tree hierarchy as shown below:

```
{

    "name": "World",
    "children": [
      { "name": "US",
          "children": [
           { "name": "CA" },
           { "name": "NJ" }
         ]
      },
      { "name": "INDIA",
          "children": [
          { "name": "OR" },
          { "name": "TN" },
          { "name": "AP" }
         ]
      }
 ]
};
```

Then this tree will be used for tree visualization. Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

d3.nest is your friend!

Look at the Nest documentation for D3: https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nests

And here are some example I wrote when I was learning to use nest: https://gist.github.com/3176159

This question also helps:  [D3: use nest function to turn flat data with parent key into a hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934862/d3-use-nest-function-to-turn-flat-data-with-parent-key-into-a-hierarchy)

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped a lot.
One more query though : can we change the tags of the hierarchy formed from d3.nset()
In your examples you have "key" and "values" as tags where as I wanted to have my tags as "name" and "children".
Any idea how to do this??