# csv data to nested json tree in d3

Tags: javascript, json, csv, tree, d3.js

I have a csv data file which looks like this

```
root,y,i,5
root,c,b,a,7
root,c,b,z,2
```

I'd like to generate something  similar to the [flare.json](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/flare.json) data file like this:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "y",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "i",
          "value": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "c",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "b",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "a",
              "value": 7
            },
            {
              "name": "z",
              "value": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've seen others address a [similar question]([Create hierarchy from csv in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495112/create-hierarchy-from-csv-in-d3-js), but the data is even in the sense  that every csv row has exactly `n` elements. I have varied lengths of `n`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It sounds like you would want to change whatever generates that data to generate a hierarchical structure. CSV isn't really meant for ragged formats like this and you will run into difficulties just processing it.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the d3 nest function to accomplish this. You can find documentation on how to use it here: http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/

The solution would look something like this:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d[0]; })
  .key(function(d) { return d[1]; })
  .entries(csv_data);
```

Comment: This will only work if you have a defined number of columns. No? My problem is that my columns are variable.

Comment: if you only want to group by the first two columns, this should be fine. If you need to go with arbitrary columns, you could combine this with underscore.js, and traverse through the new nested data, nesting again when appropriate.